# Concatenation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate numbers in cells A1:A100 in to a single string. How do I do that referencing another sheet.Code is as follows

```
Sheets("Current").Cells(1,1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Reference Sheet'!A1:A100)"
```

But I am not getting anything. Please help

Comment: Where would you like to put the result string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a one-liner:

```
MsgBox Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A100")), vbNullString)
```

Comment: Thank you that works, is it possible to add a space between every cell value as this results in to continuous cell values?

Comment: @meesha replace vbnullstring with chr(32)

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim oRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim concStr as String

Set oRng = Range("A1:A100")
concStr = vbNullString

For Each cel in oRng

    concStr = concStr & cel.value

Next cel

''Do stuff with concStr
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CONCATENATE` function doesn't work on a range but on separate cells, i.e. `CONCATENATE('Reference Sheet'!A1,'Reference Sheet'!A2,'Reference Sheet'!A3)`. If you always have 100 cells then you could use a loop:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim formulaString As String

formulaString= "=CONCATENATE("
For x = 1 To 100
    formulaString= formulaString & "'Reference Sheet'!A" & x & ","
Next x
' Remove last comma
formulaString= Left(formulaString, Len(formulaString) - 1)
' Add closing bracket
formulaString= formulaString& ")"
Sheets("Current").Cells(1,1).Formula = formulaString
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with arrays, first create an array to hold the input value `"A1:A100"`.
Then convert all *numbers* to *strings* within the array and join the array to obtain the resulting string and enter it in the required cell.

For this code using worksheets named *"Source"* and "Target" *(modify as required)*

Pls check comments in the code and see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098.aspx

```
Sub Rng_ConcatenateValues()
Dim aArySrc As Variant, vArySrc As Variant, sAryTrg As String
Dim l As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Rem Set Input Array
        aArySrc = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:A100"))
        Rem Convert values to string
        For l = LBound(aArySrc) To UBound(aArySrc)
            aArySrc(l) = CStr(aArySrc(l))
        Next
        Rem Join Array Values
        sAryTrg = Join(aArySrc, Chr(133))
        Rem Post Resulting Concatenation
        .Worksheets("Target").Cells(1).Value = sAryTrg
    End With
End Sub
```